# Realtek ALC 3661

Tags: 14.04, realtek, alienware

I have a 2014 Alienware Laptop and want to install Kubuntu on my secondary HDD.
Everything is working perfectly, except for the Sound. I tried everything, but I can't get the internal speakers to work, the headphone outputs are working perfectly. Everything shows up nicely, but also changig the profile as well as trying every output didn't help. As far as I can tell, the model of my sound chip is the ALC3661 (that's what it's called on Dell's drivers page). I use kubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

<del>I have made some headway with this, but it's not perfect.</del> **I've made a lot of progress with this. It's a lot closer to perfect now, so I've decided to largely rewrite this post/answer.** The chipset is not fully supported. As you've no doubt noticed, the stock drivers and many other tools misidentify this as the ALC668 chipset. `lshw -c sound` shows "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset". Not very helpful :(

Anyway, you'll need the alsa-tools package, specifically the HDA Jack Retasking tool, and the official drivers from Realtek. The HDA retasking tool requires gksudo, so you will want to create a "shim" that runs kdesudo; I ran (as root) `update-alternatives /usr/bin/gksudo gui-sudo /usr/bin/kdesudo`. You may just opt to create the symlink directly.

- After compiling and installing the realtek drivers, reboot, login, and run "killall pulseaudio" (doesn't have to be root - pulseaudio runs as a user daemon) and run the HDA jack retasking tool.
- Select "Show unconnected pins" and "Advanced override".
- Override all speakers and headphones (the mics can be left alone - I haven't done much testing with them) and set them to "Not connected". Click "Apply Now".
- In a terminal run `pulseaudio --start --daemonize=0 --log-target=stderr`; you should get an error (because you have no output).

What follows may involve a lot of playing around with it if you don't have the exact same setup I do. I'll outline the process I went through, then my specific pin configuration.

First we'll map out what jacks are actually available for speakers. Some labeled "not connected" are available, some aren't.

- You'll see that by default certain channel groups are already assigned. Pick an unassigned channel group (or the one already assigned to some speaker jacks); I'll assume "1".
- Override the Internal Speaker, set it to "internal" connectivity, channel group "1", and "Front" for the "channel (in group)".
- Override the headphone slots, set the connectivity to "not connected" (we'll come back to those).
- Override all remaining output slots (speakers, headphones, whatever) and set to "not connected". You should have only one output slot, labeled "speaker", connected via "internal", to channel group "1", on the "front" channel-in-group.
- Click "Apply now". You might have to re-run the pulseaudio command, but your multimedia system settings might take care of that for you.
- You will have to run the audio settings every time though. Open System Settings -> Multimedia -> Audio and Video settings -> Audio hardware setup -> Sound Card: Built in audio. You should only have "stereo" available, but both speakers should work (and sound should come out the correct speaker).

  - If they don't, go back to the retasking tool and use a different slot for your "1"-"front" speakers, making sure all other outputs are "not connected".
- After testing the speakers, go back to the retasking tool and set one of the other slots labeled "speaker" or "not connected" to:

  - Connectivity: Internal
  - Location: Internal*
  - Device: Speaker
  - Jack: ATAPI*
  - Color: Unknown*
  - Jack Detection: Not Present
  - Channel group: 1
  - Channel (in group): Back
- Rerun the multimedia settings and check that you have 4.0 surround sound available. Whether the speakers actually work is irrelevant, we just want to make sure that the pins can be detected when assigned. Make a note of whether the slot works or not. Reset the connectivity to "not connected" and make sure you have only stereo available again. Then test the next slot.

One of the things that makes it so tedious is that some of the pins seem to be actually disconnected. Some of the settings in the HDA jack retasking tool (which I've marked with an asterisk) seem to be purely informational. I'm not entirely sure what effect the "channel (in group)" has, because (by the audio settings tool) it's impossible to have a "center" speaker without front and back stereo speakers. And if you have too many pins assigned to the same channel, the driver freaks out and gives up until you reassign some pins. Sometimes it freaks out permanently and you have to reboot. Also, sometimes the jack retasking tool cannot read some of the options after reboot, so be sure to take notes on what you set if it almost works good.

Anyway, now that you have the pins mapped out, we get to assigning them. One by one, set and test them, assigning them to all the same as above except the "channel (in group)" should be (progressively) "back", "center/lfe", "side", and maybe "channel X & Y" if you have more connectable pins. Each time you add one, go back to the multimedia panel and test your speakers in all available configurations.

Once you have all the pins connected, you might try playing around with which ones are assigned to which "channel (in group)", or disconnecting some. Due to the way the internal data streams are laid out, you might end up with 7.1 surround sound, where all the speaker buttons make sound except the "back" ones, even though the 5.1 configuration sounds the best. You might also (like me) end up with an extra set of bogus pins connected to "channel 8 & 9" (or whatever) - if I disconnect them, I lose some of my working speakers; if I mark them as "back", they shift around in weird ways (the "front" buttons don't work, the "center" button sounds out the left speaker, the "subwoofer" button sounds out the right... this might have been me messing up the tedium and getting sloppy with my notes...).

When you have all the speakers working satisfactorily, click "Install boot override" in the HDA retasking tool and (after making sure you have all your notes) reboot. Test your speakers.

Finally you can add back your headphones - set the connectivity to "jack" and the channel to the same as your speakers ("1"). Be sure to set "jack detection" to "present", and the "device" to "headphones". This should make it so that when you plug in the headphones, the speakers cut off. It's probably best to just leave the speakers on the "front" channel-in-group. One odd thing, I did notice the sound was a bit higher pitched until I assigned some headphone pins, I don't know why.

Also, refer back to your notes. You'll want to re-set any speaker jacks that got "lost" after reboot.

My pin configuration is as follows. I kept my notes in LibreOffice Calc. I also don't use one of my headphone jacks, but I filled in all the info just in case I want to change my mind.

Good Luck!

---

```
Pin   - "Name / Label", (details on next lines)

0x12  - "Internal Mic, ATAPI", (not overriden)
0x19  - "Black Mic, Left Side", (not overridden)
0x1b  - "Not Connected", (not overridden)
0x1d  - "Not Connected", (not overridden)
0x1f  - "Not Connected", (not overridden)

0x14  - "Internal Speaker", Connectivity "internal"
        Device "speaker", Channel [in group] "1 [front]"
        Location "internal", Jack "atapi", Color "unknown", Jack Det. "not present"

0x15  - "Black Headphone, Left Side", Connectivity "not connected",
        Device "headphone", Channel [in group] "1 [front]"
        Location "left", Jack "combination", Color "black", Jack Det. "present"

0x16  - "Black Headphone, Left Side", Connectivity "jack",
        Device "headphone", Channel [in group] "1 [front]"
        Location "left", Jack "3.5 mm", Color "black", Jack Det. "present"

0x18  - "Not Connected", Connectivity "internal",
        Device "speaker", Channel [in group] "1 [8 & 9]"
        Location "internal", Jack "atapi", Color "unknown", Jack Det. "not present"

0x1a  - "Not connected", Connectivity "internal",
        Device "speaker", Channel [in group] "1 [center/LFE]"
        Location "internal", Jack "atapi", Color "unknown", Jack Det. "not present"

0x1e  - "Not Connected", Connectivity "internal",
        Device "speaker", Channel [in group] "1 [side]"
        Location "internal", Jack "atapi", Color "unknown", Jack Det. "not present"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get the latest alsa dev working (2016-04-02) by following the instructions here (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa), installing the "alsa daily development build" and rebooting. If you've followed the instructions in my previous answer, you can simply "remove the boot profile" and reboot. It now correctly identifies the chipset, and the audio speakers and headphones (including jack detection) works sensibly.